# radius search by latitude / longitude

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, geolocation

I have found a bunch of answers for this question using mysql , but I wasn't able to convert anything into a query ms sql 2008 can use.  I have a longitude and latitude column for each row in the database.  I am going to have a latitude and longitude for where the user is.  I want to be able to find all rows that are within x miles from the user's latitude/longitude.  Also when trying to use other queries I found on SO I keep getting the error  -  `'pow' is not a recognized built-in function name.`  which is weird , because I'm pretty sure that I have used `pow` before in sql 2008.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  So far this is the closest  could come up with.

```
select * from tbl_MyTable
WHERE (
POW( ( 69.1 * ( Longitude - @longitude ) * cos( @latitude / 57.3 ) ) , 2 ) + POW( ( 69.1 * ( Latitude - @latitude ) ) , 2 )
) < ( 5 *5 );
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Since you're on SQL 2008, consider using the native geospatial capabilities. You can do fancy things like:

- Create a persisted computed column of geography type that represents your point.
- Create a spatial index on the computed column. This will make things like `yourPoint.STDistance(@otherPoint) <= @distance` efficient

Like so:

```
alter table [yourTable] add [p] as geography::Point(Latitude, Longitude, 4326) persisted;
create spatial index [yourSpatialIndex] on [yourTable] ([p])

declare @Latitude float = <somevalue>, @Longitude float = <somevalue>;
declare @point geography = geography::Point(@Latitude, @Longitude, 4326);
declare @distance int = <distance in meters>;

select * from [yourTable] where @point.STDistance([p]) <= @distance;
```

Comment: do you have a link for setting that up? I thought that was something new in ms sql 2012

Comment: awesome , thanks man , this is a way better answer, I don't want to take away from derek's accept answer since he technically did answer my question and was first

Comment: ohhhhh- wait , what is 4326 in there?  Do I need 4152 for North America ??

Comment: 4226 is what's called an SRID, or a spatial reference identifier. As is the case with many things, there are a lot of competing standards for geospatial data representation. All of the SRIDs that SQL Server knows about are in a system view called sys.spatial_reference_systems.

Comment: looks like geography type columns can't be persisted

Comment: Ah, you're right (though I though I'd done this before). You can accomplish the same thing though with a non-computed column and a trigger to keep it up to date.

Comment: You can persist the geography computed column in SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 7):

```
DECLARE @CurrentLocation geography; 
SET @CurrentLocation  = geography::Point(12.822222, 80.222222, 4326)

SELECT * , Round (GeoLocation.STDistance(@CurrentLocation ),0) AS Distance FROM [Landmark]
WHERE GeoLocation.STDistance(@CurrentLocation )<= 2000 -- 2 Km
```

Wonderful Tutorial

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/convert-latitude-longitude-to-geography-point.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I think you want POWER not POW

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174276.aspx

Comment: this did fix it , but Ben wrote out a whole indexed faster smarter way of performing this query

Comment: It's all good, in the words of an anonymous chess grandmaster: "When I find a good move, I look for a better move".