# Check for geolocation already in my Database

Tags: sql-server, geolocation

I get mobile my current geolocation (long./lat.) , i will store this geolocation online in a sql server 2008 Database. How can i check that i not already have this location (maybe in an radius of 100 meter)?

Comment: I answered a similar question [here][1]. See if you can use that.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628794/radius-search-by-latitude-longitude/15640498#15640498

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of that does this is an WHERE NOT EXISTS (location within 100 meters.)

Here is a sample implementation for this:

```
--A table with some coordinates.
create table #myexistinglocations
(id int identity(1,1) primary key clustered not null
,location geography not null
,shortdescription varchar(30) null
)
insert into #myexistinglocations
values(geography::Point(40.750508,-73.993735,4326),'Madison Square Garden')
,(geography::Point(40.705524,-74.01351,4326),'Charging Bull')
;

WITH myNewLocations(l,sd) --Represents the new stuff I want to put in.
as
(
SELECT geography::Point(40.70585,-74.013486,4326),'Wall Street bull!'
UNION ALL SELECT geography::Point(40.713728,-73.990173,4326),'East Broadway!'
)
SELECT
*
FROM myNewLocations as a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #myexistinglocations as b WHERE b.location.STDistance ( a.l ) <= 100)
```

The last row is what is essential to your question. Only "East Broadway!" will be returned since "Wall Street bull!" is too close to an existing location.