# SQL Server Find Records Within A certain Distance

Tags: sql-server, geospatial, spatial-query

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I have a table with addresses and wish to find other addresses within say 500 feet of it. Is there a query I can write to do this task? Do I need to geo code the addresses first?

Thanks

Comment: How would you calculate distance without some form of geocoding?

Comment: do you have the record of addresses that are 50 feet away in your database table??

Comment: yes, all records are in table. some closer than 500 feet, some farther than 500 feet.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026675/calculating-distance-between-two-points-latitude-longitude
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628794/radius-search-by-latitude-longitude
And yes you will need geo code first